# Is it safe to put thin insulation board on the bottom of joists in crawlspace?

Tags: insulation, joists, moisture, crawlspace

My townhouse has a partial lower level and partial crawlspace of dirt. Rooms with crawlspace under get pretty cold in winter. There is some un-faced (I think) fiberglass roll insulation tucked up between the joists, although some has come down.

The crawlspace is fairly dry and has good airflow. I'm not able to encapsulate or whatever. Local weather goes from just below freezing to hot and humid. I can manage to lay on my back in there and staple up some 4x8 foot sheets of half inch or so insulation board if it will help. I think that the floors will be warmer because winter air won't blow right against the joist spaces.

the lower level ends in a concrete block wall which supports the middle of the building. There is one too-small opening which we are going to permanently close and seal, in a closet. The crawlspace runs all the way under this six unit building, with access at each end and plenty of vents. The water heater is under there too (HVAC got too big, I guess). There is some poly on the dirt, but it's mostly pushed all over by some past work or something (I'm new here). Radon inside in lower level tested about 1.5 twice. We own our unit but not the building so we can't do major work.

Is rigid insulation board a good idea? I can't get it air tight due to pipes and wiring on underside of joists. Would board cause moisture issues in the floor joist area, and is there a better idea? If it is good, should I get the silver faced board, and which side up? This is super helpful to me, with not much money to spend and willing to get filthy under there... Again!

Comment: how is your lower level connected to the crawl, access door?  it sounds like the crawl space is vented?  Do you have poly on your dirt floor?  Do you live in a radon hazard region?  Could you dig out your crawl and make it living space?

Comment: (I moved my answering comment in to the question)

Answer (score 1):

If this is about comfort then there are options.  If you expect to re-coup your material money packback will likely be 10+ years.

I'd start with adding roxul to the joists bays and then use intello stapled to the underside of the joists.  The intello will allow moisture to pass through, hold the insulation in place and provide a wind break.  You could try it just on one area of floor and see how much better it seems before using the solution across the board.  Tape the perimeter of the intelligent wrb with something cheap like tuck tape.  That should cut the wind cooling factor down considerably and be pretty cheap / easy.

Comment: A/C runs about as much as heat and costs about as much. Being sandwiched between other units, with some shade trees helps. I'm not really trying to save money, the floor is just cold. The crawlspace is common area but I don't think they'll mind me putting up some reasonable insulation on 'my' floor. Probably can't get air seal because there are pipes and wiring stapled under the joists in places. I was going to fit insulation board around things, but not air tight. It's going to be a nightmare project as is. I put a new smooth dryer duct in last summer and my wife's ears still hurt :-)